# Jackson wrapper deserialization best practices

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

I have the following JSON and I would like to parse it using Jackson JSON Processor library (http://jackson.codehaus.org/):

```
{
    "wrapper":{
        "general":{
            "value":10
        },
        "items":{
            "DOG":{
                "0":78,
                "1":125
                "name":"Lucky",
                "features":{
                    "color":"brown",
                    "sex":"male"
                }
            },
            "CAT":{
                "0":123,
                "1":94
                "name":"Fluffy",
                "features":{
                    "color":"black",
                    "sex":"female"
                }
            },
            "MOUSE":{
                "0":23,
                "1":33
                "name":"Jerry",
                "features":{
                    "color":"gray",
                    "sex":"male"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How would you suggest to be the best way in terms of best practices?

Comment: Jackson ? what is that

Comment: @MT8 It's a JSON library. He should read the manual instead of asking here.

Comment: ok i hv use GSON lib but i think using lib make heap problem ...parse it directly

Comment: @Kayaman Can you point me to the right link? How could I manage the wapper ?

Comment: Make a wrapper class? What's your real issue here?

Comment: I have no big issue, I was just wondering is there is a best way of doing it in terms of best practices. Probably I should have been more specific in the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple and quick form to parse that JSON is create a bean with annotation and then call Jackson.

Some like this:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class YourClass {

@JsonProperty("wrapper")
public Wrapper wrapper;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public static class Wrapper{
        @JsonProperty("Items")
        public ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
}


@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public static class Item{
        @JsonProperty("name")
        public String name;
        ...
}

....
```

}

Then in your Activity/Thread/AsyncTask:

```
  public ObjectMapper mMapper;

  ...

  if (mMapper == null)
      mMapper = new ObjectMapper();
  YourClass yourClass = (YourClass) mMapper.readValue(stringJSON, YourClas.class);
```

*It's very important that you reuse the ObjectMapper becasue instanciate it it's very expensive*

*Improvement*: That JSON could be improve if you set this (the bean is based in it)

```
{  
  "wrapper":{  
    "general":{
        "value":10
    },
    "items":[  
        "item":{      
            "name":"DOG",  
            "0":78,  
            "1":125
            "name":"Lucky",
            "features":{
                "color":"brown",
                "sex":"male"
            }
        },
        "item":{
            "name":"CAT",
            "0":123,
            "1":94
            "name":"Fluffy",
            "features":{
                "color":"black",
                "sex":"female"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Sadly I cannot change the JSON structure, I just have to adapt my code on it

Comment: Anyway, modify the annotations to feet with the json :)